# User has_many reviews association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a way for users to review other users.

When I try going on www.site.com/users/1/reviews/new , i get redirected to my homepage with 'resource not found'. I'm guessing it has to do with my routes?

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users,
    :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations',
                      omniauth_callbacks:  'omniauth_callbacks'} #<-- that thing is for STRIPE!
  #STRIPE
  resources :charges
  #MAILBOXER
  resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
      member do
        post :reply
        post :restore
        post :mark_as_read
      end
      collection do
        delete :empty_trash
      end
  end
  resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]

  #user reviews (THE PROBLEM)
  resources :users do
    resources :reviews
  end
```

#categories associatoin
  resources :categories, except: [:destroy]

root 'home#index'
  get 'profile', to: 'users#show'

end

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable
  #Categories association stuff
  has_many :user_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :user_categories

  #user review association stuff 
  has_many :reviews


  acts_as_messageable

  def mailboxer_email(object)
    email
  end
end
```

review.rb

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

reviews_controller.rb

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_user
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  # GET /reviews
  # GET /reviews.json
  def index
    @reviews = Review.all
  end

  # GET /reviews/1
  # GET /reviews/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /reviews/new
  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  # GET /reviews/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reviews
  # POST /reviews.json
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.user_id = @user.id
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.update(review_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reviews/1
  # DELETE /reviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reviews_url, notice: 'Review was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
    end
end
```

Comment: I can't immediately see the cause of the error, but a few things I could point out. Your `set_user` method should be using `params[:user_id]`. Also your create action, seems to be setting the `user_id` twice. I guess you may want to use either current_user or @user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

should be:

```
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```